# Coordinate Geometry

Tags: calculus

For the curve $y= \dfrac{x^2}{e^x}$ for $x$ between $0$ to $3$ inclusive, find the $x$ coordinate of the point $P$ at which the tangent to the curve passes through the origin.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know the general form for the tangent line at a generic point of that curve?

Comment: i tried equating y/x with the derivative of the curve, didnt get anywhere with that

Comment: Why would you do such a thing? I mean, what's your approach?

Comment: because the gradient at point p is given by y/x and the gradient of  the curve at any point is given by its derivative and both of them need to be the same at point p

Comment: yes...and I still don't get you. Read my answer, perhaps it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Use the quotient rule for derivative:

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{e^x}\implies f'(x)=\frac{2x-x^2}{e^x}\implies$$

the tangent line at point $\;(x_0,y_0)\;$ on the curve is given by

$$y-y_0=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

Now, check when $\;y_0-f'(x_0)x_0=0\;$ (why?) . Also, note that

$$y_0=\frac{x_0^2}{e^{x_0}}$$

Comment: i'm not getting the answer man

Comment: tried it this way about 10 times

Comment: @user140161, when does the line $\;y=mx+b\;$ passes through the origin? There you go...!

Comment: when b is zero. what are you trying to say?

Comment: Well @user140161, what do you think my last two lines point to?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f'$ gives you the tangent at any point on the curve. Solve for the point this way: $y-y_1 = f'(x-x_1)$ where $(x_1,y_1)=(0,0)$ and $x,y's$ relationship is given by our function.

Comment: That's exactly what i did, didnt work